# How to keep UTF -8 encoding when using read csv in R?

Tags: r, csv, encoding, utf-8, read.csv

I encountered a problem of lossing file encoding UTF - 8 when using

```
read.csv
```

in R. That resulted in e.g. Latin letters replaced by not desired signs, e.g.:  IguaÃ§u.

I tried using following with FileEncoding argument:

```
read.csv(xx.csv, fileEncoding = 'UTF-8')
read.csv2(xx.csv, fileEncoding = 'UTF-8')
```

but got error:

```
Warning messages:1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  invalid input found on input connection 'C:/xxx.csv'
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:/xxx.csv'
```

What is the solution to keep the UTF-8 encoding when reading csv into R?

Comment: Try using `Encoding = "UTF-8"` instead of fileEncoding.

Answer (score 3):

So by trial and error method, I found out that using function from `readr` package

```
read_csv
```

instead of

```
read.csv
read.csv2
```

without any fileEncoding argument does the work and the encoding is being kept.
Hope that might help someone.

Comment: You should mention that `read_csv` comes from the __readr__ package.